# problem route reactjs with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

i created a route with react-router-dom like the attached code below, LoginContainer and RegisterContainer are running normally and the problem is in the default container. in defaultContainer I can only visit url: '/', when I switch to url: '/work' or something else in DefaultContainer the application still displays the homePage even though the url has switched to its destination

*/App.js*

```
const App = () => {
    // another code
    return (
        <SimpleBarReact style={{ maxHeight: dimensions }}>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/(login)" component={LoginContainer} />
                    <Route exact path="/(register)" component={RegisterContainer} />
                    <Route path="/" component={DefaultContainer} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </SimpleBarReact>
    )
}

const LoginContainer = () => (
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/login" /> } />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    </div>
)

const RegisterContainer = () => (
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/register" /> } />
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
    </div>
)

const DefaultContainer = () => (
    <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/work" component={Work}/>
        <Route path="/work-detile" component={WorkDetile}/>
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard/>
        </ProtectedRoute>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/project-list">
            <ProjectList/>
        </ProtectedRoute>
   </div>
)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The matching pattern of `path` in Route always works like the pattern working to find a text without considering their case sensitivity.

Let me explain that using an example.

When a user requests **/work** from browser, React Router can be returned,

- `<Route exact path="/work" component={Work}/>`

or

- `<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>`

Because React Router literally compares the *browser URL* & *path* only when you pass `exact` prop to the Route component.

```js
<Route exact path="/work" component={Home}/>
```

So as a best practice always add the root level route to the end of all the others & pass the `exact` prop to that.

```js
const DefaultContainer = () => (
    <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Route path="/work" component={Work}/>
        <Route path="/work-detile" component={WorkDetile}/>
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard/>
        </ProtectedRoute>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/project-list">
            <ProjectList/>
        </ProtectedRoute>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
   </div>
)
```

Let me know if you need further support.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code help you

```
const App = () => {
    // another code
    return (
        <SimpleBarReact style={{ maxHeight: dimensions }}>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginContainer} />
                    <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterContainer} />
                    <Route path="/" component={DefaultContainer} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </SimpleBarReact>
    )
}

const LoginContainer = () => (
    <div>  
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Redirect to="/login" />
    </div>
)

const RegisterContainer = () => (
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Redirect to="/register" />
    </div>
)

const DefaultContainer = () => (
    <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path="/work" component={Work}/>
        <Route exact path="/work-detile" component={WorkDetile}/>
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard/>
        </ProtectedRoute>
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/project-list">
            <ProjectList/>
        </ProtectedRoute>
   </div>
)
```

Comment: i not edit another code. i just add exact in all Route in DefaultContainer